# How to select a item from drop-down, with select class name

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to select a value from Drop-Down in DHTML Grid Using Selenium WebDriver?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBpyD.png)

By Double click in UMO Column, a drop-down will be seen.

I need to pick a item from that drop-down. But locator is unable to find the Drop-Down.

I am able to double click the field, not able to proceed after that(i.e., Control is not able to locate the drop-down).

Through Firebug, it is shown "Select Class"..

Is there any work around in selenium webdriver to select the item from that drop-down...?

Will be very helpful if u share idea regarding this.

Comment: Please include the HTML Grid or sample codes that you are working on

Comment: <select class="dhx_combo_select" style="width: 120px; left: 483px; top: 324px;" size="6">
<option value="0">--Select--</option>
<option value="514">Case</option>
<option value="515">MSQ</option>
<option value="516">Piece</option>
</select>

Answer (score 1):

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("<className>"))).SelectByIndex("");

new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("<className>"))).SelectByText("");

 new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("<className>"))).SelectByValue("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code that may help. Create a instance of Select Class from WebElement.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select");
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("iframeResult")));
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.tagName("select"));
    Select se=new Select(elem);
    se.selectByIndex(3);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver .close();

}
```

Comment: Answers should include only the relevant code, not the entire class from your project.

Answer (score 0):

WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"institutionName\"]/option"));

Select select = new Select(element);

```
    select.selectByVisibleText("value");

    //select.selectByIndex(0);

    //select.selectByValue("1");
```